# XmlWriter The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I am using an XmlWriter and getting the following error:

```
Invalid name character in 'news:news'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

does anyone have any idea what is causing this? here is my code:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("moo.xml"))
            {               

                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "news", null, "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9");


                writer.WriteStartElement("url");
                writer.WriteElementString("loc", "http://www.monkeys.co.uk");

                writer.WriteStartElement("news:news");
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteEndElement();



                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();

            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the overload of [`WriteStartElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7579ed08.aspx) that takes two parameters:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("news", "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9");
//               Tag   ----^       ^--- Namespace
```

Comment: @Funky: Instead of `writer.WriteStartElement("news:news");`. It will result in this tag: `<news:news />`. Because the URI is already known as a namespace to the writer it uses the prefix registered for that URI.

Comment: @Funky: BTW: Is there a specific reason why you are not using XmlDocument or XDocument (prefered)?. XmlWriter normally is only used in scenarios where you have a *huge* amount of data that would be problematic to keep in memory at once.

Comment: no, there's no specific reason, I just saw it on a tutorial and went with that, I will now look into XmlDocument and XDocument as you said it is prefered for this type of thing

Comment: @Funky: Yes, look into XDocument. It is a *lot* simpler, especially when you work with complicated XML structures.